# Google maps componentRestrictions not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps javascript api places SearchBox with componentRestrictions settings to country cz.

But getting autocomplete with all countries.

```
const AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTIONS = {
 types: ['address'],
 componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'cz'
 }
};
new google.maps.places.SearchBox(inputPlaceElement, AUTOCOMPLETE_OPTIONS);
```

If dump created object to console componentRestrictions is set as I want but in request url there is nothing about this restriction there should be GetPredictions not GetQueryPredictions:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AutocompletionService.GetQueryPredictions?1sb&4scs&15e3
```

I'm not sure where is problem here, if I set other country code it's not working either.

Comment: Turn this into an Autocomplete. As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBoxOptions) you can only bias the predictions with a `LatLngBounds` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `componentRestrictions` are not supported by [`SearchBox`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBoxOptions), this option applies to [`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions)